# Difference between Heuristic Search and Informed Search

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am a bit confused between these two terms: `Heuristic Search` and `Informed Search`. I understand both require knowledge to have a better performance than blind searches, but is there any *significant* difference?

Answer (score 2):

There is **no difference**.

In the field of Heuristic Search in Artificial Intelligence, a heuristic function is a function that uses knowledge about the problem to estimate "how far" a state is from the goal. Using this function, algorithms like A* can generally expand a smaller number of nodes than blind search algorithms like Dijkstra's algorithm. This is why Informed search is a **synonym** for Heuristic Search, which is a search with information of the problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Informed search is the same as heuristic search.

These slides explain the basic approaches and are based on Rusell/Norvig AIMA. You can find a nice explanation in section 3.5 (2010 edition)